# Is there any way I can program stm32f103c8t6 through usb to ttl converter and using keil uvision 5?

Tags: stm32, bootloader, keil

I always get noUlink device found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [Application](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf) note:

Please note that, **yes it is possible to program the microcontroller using USB to TTL cable you have got**.

You need to use ST software on the computer for that which will connect to the MCU through the specific UART interface on the board. The application note gives idea on which UART ports can be used and also about the ST software to be used. This information and Boot Pin configuration setting ( from application note again) should solve it.

Any reason why you have to use keil software only for programming?

**If you are planning to debug the code, then you have to have a debugger** whether standalone (ST Link, JLink ) or a Nucleo or other ST boards which have a dedicated STLink part in it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created a bin file from my project in keil and flashed this bin file to the stm32 using flash loader. But it does not seem to be working. i know there is no problem with connections and the code.  But I am not sure about the way I create the bin file. Could you guide me on how I can create a file from project properly so that I can flah it to the card and get it working?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boXSdDnHaAE  there can be problem with code too. I suggest to try basic LED or PIN toggling code

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a Segger J-Link - rather expensive. Cheapest solution is to buy an STM32 Discovery board (virtually any of them will do) which has an on-board programmer, and use that to program your device. It will have a connector and jumper which enable it to be used with external devices.

Comment: The programmer on-board the STM32 Discovery (and Nucleo) boards is an ST-Link, not a J-Link. A standalone ST-Link is not expensive, either -- it's roughly $20.

Comment: Or a chinese knockoff for $3.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Duskwuff. I bought the ST-Link V2 a few months ago, and it was around $20. It's very simple to use, and almost works plug-and-play. No fumbling around with custom headers and having another big annoying PCB on your table. ST-Link V2 is the way to go.